# mysql_num_rows not working sort of

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, mysql-num-rows

I got this

```
for($i = 1; $i < 301; $i++)
{
    $r8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM full_dump WHERE id_fd='".$last_id."' AND field_".$i." LIKE '%JAL?%' order by field_".$i." desc limit 0,1")or die(mysql_error());
    if ( mysql_num_rows($r8) == 1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r8))
        {
            $i4 = $i+1;
            $jalfd = trim($row['field_'.$i4.'']);
        }
    }
    else {
        $jalfd = "N/A";
    }
}
```

It is part of a pile_upload script. All works but  not this.
When I upload a file it may or may not contain the word JAL? and the next line has its value. No matter what, the end value of jalfd is N/A.  When I do

```
echo mysql_num_rows($r8);
```

I get the following when I have JAL? in the text file (you'll see a 1 in there)

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

an when I don't have JAL? (there is no 1)

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I even tried

```
if ( intval(mysql_num_rows($r8)) == 1){
```

with no luck.

Comment: what is difference given two output?

Comment: don't use mysql_* instead use mysqli_* or PDO, mysql_ already deprecated and may be removed in the next version

Comment: I can see a '1' for the case where there is no jal

Comment: sorry about that. I copied the wrong thing. I've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No matter what, the end value of jalfd is N/A

With your Logic, the value of `$jalfd` after the end of the loop only depends upon your 300th loop iteration. On every iteration you are overwriting it. If your 300th iteration resulted in rows not being `1` you will get `$jalfd="N/A"` regardless of what the previous values were.

A simple fix using your design itself, will be to initialize the value

```
$jalfd = "N/A";
```

before your loop starts, and remove the `else` section completely. It wont be needed then.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The reason why I use the loop, is that the files I upload is each different in the number of lines is has.